# ExtendedFormAuthenticator in JBoss 7

Tags: authentication, jboss7.x

I'm porting a legacy application from JBoss 4.2.3 to JBoss 7 (the web profile version). They used a custom login module and used a valve to capture the login failure reason into j_exception. They did this by putting context.xml into the web-inf directory of the war, with the following contents:

```
<!-- Add the ExtendedFormAuthenticator to get access to the username/password/exception ->
<Context cookies="true" crossContext="true">
<Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.ExtendedFormAuthenticator"
       includePassword="true" ></Valve>
</Context>
```

The login is working for me, but not that valve. When there's a login exception, the j_exception is still empty and the logic that depends on analyzing why the login was rejected fails. According to this link: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExtendedFormAuthenticator, everything looks right. However that link is very old, and it's possible things have changed since then. What's the new way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that security valves are now defined directly in jboss-web.xml, like this:

```
<jboss-web>
<security-domain>mydomain</security-domain>   
<valve>
       <class-name>org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.ExtendedFormAuthenticator</class-name>
       <param>
           <param-name>includePassword</param-name>
           <param-value>true</param-value>
       </param>
    </valve>
</jboss-web>
```

However, the ExtendedFormAuthenticator class wasn't ported to JBoss 7.0.1. A ticket has been opened for me, so it should be present in JBoss 7.1.0: 
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1963